# Pidgin windows placement on Windows 7 - forgets preferences

Tags: windows-7, window, pidgin

I run [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im) as my IM client.

Until recently (no updates to Pidgin, and only security updates for Windows), my buddy list would open on the left side of my screen, and the current chat window would open and anchor to the right side.

However, starting about 2 weeks ago, new IM windows are now defaulting to the left side of the screen along with my buddy list.

Is there a way to fix this behavior back to how it used to be?

Answer (score 0):

try using shellfolderfix. It remembers where you position your windows ( and how big they are):

http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html